# How can I configure the Java generated code for composed grammar in Antlr4 Maven plugin (no static classes, no final methods)?

Tags: java, maven, antlr4, maven-plugin

I have my grammar, written in Antlr4, which extends SQL grammar, in particular PostgreSQL one. For this latter, I have a separated `.g4` file which is imported in my grammar's `.g4` file. When I generate the Java code using `mvn package`, it creates separated file for each grammar, in particular it defines my grammar's Java classes to extend PostgreSQL ones, as I used the `superClass` option in my `.g4` files.
The problem is that all the generated Java classes are declared `static` and all the methods inside them are `final`. This seems to me to be half work done, since the plugin offers the possibility to have super grammar but it generates incorrect Java classes.

Is there a way to configure Antlr4 Maven plugin to generate non-`static` classes and non-`final` methods?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure Antlr4 Maven plugin to generate non-static classes and non-final methods?

No.

You don't explain why this is a problem for you, but I think that instead of using `superClass`, you should be using using [ANTLR's import feature](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md#grammar-imports):

```
grammar YourGrammar;

import PostgreSQLParser;

your_parser_rule
 : select_stmt // <- from PostgreSQLParser
 | your_stmt
 ;

your_stmt
 : ...
 ;
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I did use the import statement in the .g4 files but the code generator  of the plugin creates separated classes for PostgreSQL and my grammar. That's why I used the superClass to let code generator know that I want my grammar's Java classes to extend PostgreSQL ones; in this way I can use my grammar's parser to parse my language and PostgreSQL. One thing that I do not understand is why the antlr4 maven plugin does not generate Java classes for the importing grammar only including the imported grammar's parts as well.

Comment: Solved it. It was a problem of antlr maven plugin version.